# Java: How to send an email from a corporate domain

Tags: java, subdomain, jakarta-mail

I've been trying to send e-mails from a custom domain trying to log into the outlook server, since we use it as a platform to send e-mails from that direction, but it gave me an `AuthenticationFailedException`; more specifically:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [PR0P264CA0272.FRAP264.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:965)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:876)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:780)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at baseDatos.BaseDeDatos.mailMasivo(BaseDeDatos.java:595)
    at baseDatos.BaseDeDatos.main(BaseDeDatos.java:167)
```

I've been looking into some older posts that may be the solution to my problem, but I don't know how to implement it into my code.

My code looks something like this:

```
    String to = "to@mail.com";
    String from = "from@cdomain";
    String password = "password123";
    String subject = "Hello";
    BodyPart body1 = new MimeBodyPart();
    String body= "This is an e-mail";
    body1.setText(body);
    Multipart mainBody = new MimeMultipart();
    mainBody.addBodyPart(body1);
    
    String host = "outlook.office365.com";
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new OutLookAuthenticator(from, password));
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setSubject(asunto); 
    message.setContent(mainBody);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};

    message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
         
    transport.send(message);
```

### Update

I've changed the code to implement the spring framework library so I could send mail synchronously. Here's how it looks like now:

```
            JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
            mailSender.setHost("outlook.office365.com");
            mailSender.setPort(587);
            String from = keyboard.nextLine();
            mailSender.setUsername(from);
            String password = readPassword();
            mailSender.setPassword(password);

            MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

            final Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", Boolean.TRUE);
            properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", Boolean.TRUE    );
            mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(properties);
            
            try {
            final MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
            helper.setFrom(from);
            helper.setTo(to);
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            helper.setText(text, true);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mailSender.send(message);
```

And now, it is printing this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [MR2P264CA0048.FRAP264.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]

at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:440)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:361)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:356)
at baseDatos.BaseDeDatos.mailIndividual(BaseDeDatos.java:440)
at baseDatos.BaseDeDatos.main(BaseDeDatos.java:160)
```

Comment: It's difficult to say what the reason is. Please post the stackrtrace / logs from your client and the server.

Comment: @Mirko I've edited with the full stack trace; sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Clearly either `from` or `password` is wrong, or both.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I swear it isn't, I've checked and double checked and it's completely confirmed that those two are correct.

Comment: @topocart Microsoft has a lot of restrictions in their O365 solution. The next step would be getting the logs from the server.

Comment: You can swear all you like but the exception doesn't agree with you.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have wrong credentials or maybe it could be possible that the server you are hosting the project blocks some outgoing ports. For example Digital ocean blocks 25 port by default. 
 However, here you can find a solution of sending mail synchronously.
Where `this.getUsername()`, `this.getPassword()`, `this.getPort()`, `this.getHost()` are as your (mail server) credentials. 
In case you would like to send HTML in your mail as well see the `.setText()` which takes `Boolean` argument as a second argument.

*P.S
By the way I recommend you to send it in a new `Thread` as it needs time to send and then receive a response whether it is successfully or not. However, it depends on your business logic indeed.*

```
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost(this.getHost());
    mailSender.setPort(this.getPort());
    mailSender.setUsername(this.getUsername());
    mailSender.setPassword(this.getPassword());

    MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", Boolean.TRUE);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", Boolean.TRUE);
    mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(properties);

    final MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
    helper.setFrom(fromMail);
    helper.setTo(user.getEmail());
    helper.setSubject(subject);
    helper.setText("<p><strong>Welcome " + body + ",</strong></p>\n", true);
    mailSender.send(message);
```

Comment: And what do I have to put as the host? "outlook.office365.com"?

Comment: @topocart Yes, exactly if you have mail server there.

Comment: I've tried your code and changed a couple of things so I could manually write the username and its password. I set the host as "outlook.office365.com" and the port as 587. But I'm still getting errors sending the mail. I've updated the main post with the code and the stack trace.